# Dynamic menu with latest Article in drupal7

Tags: theming, routes

I'm a bit new to Drupal environment. I'm trying to develop a demo site for CMS application. Now I'm facing a difficulty to create a dynamic menu for showing taxonomy-wise latest Article. Can I do it with any existing module (Muchomenu, OM Menu etc.,)

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a module do to something like that, but you could also create your own.

You could use [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to query for the items you want and return the correct menu structure. You would need to also make sure the menu cache is rebuilt on a node save.

hook_menu should return an array of menu items, often these are pretty static however there is nothing wrong with these arrays being dynamically generated.

So you can query the node table to get a list of nodes you want, loop through these items and dynamically create an array which contains the correct menu items.

very roughly:

```
function example_menu() {
  $result = db_query('select * from node where ...'); // put in your own select items and where clause
  $menu = array();
  while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $menu['my_path/' . $row->nid;] = array(
      // See hook menu docs for what to put here.
    );
  }
  return $menu;
}
```